# Is Angular proxying my services when developing locally?

Tags: angular, web-services

During development of my angular app I've noticed in the developer console that all calls to remote services are actually being requested on localhost.  For example:

[image]

However I know this service **isn't hosted on my machine**

Therefore is Angular proxying this call?  If so why?

Comment: Are you making absolute or relative calls from your `HttpClient` services? Are you using the Angular CLI [proxy functionality](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-proxy) or the webpack support it leverages?

Comment: The env file contains relative calls but I would expect these to fail as the services are not hosted locally.  I'm not sure about the second part of your question, how would I check?

Comment: How would you check whether you're using the Angular CLI and how it's configured? I'll assume you know whether or not you're using the CLI; the docs I linked show where that config would live if you are proxying with it. But there's not nearly enough information within the question to answer it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - sorry, I'm reasonably new to angular.  Yes I am using the CLI just wasn't sure if using the proxy functionality.  I'll head off to read the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As alluded to in the comments the proxying occurs because I have a `proxy.conf.json` file which redirects all local calls appropriately - this is part of the CLI.

As far as I can tell this is to [mitigate security concerns](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/the-best-ways-to-connect-to-the-server-using-angular-cli-b0c6b699716c).